# getting error after run git push -u origin master command

Tags: wordpress, azure-devops

After run this command git push -u origin master asking me for username and password and when i enter username and password getting some error. If anyone have solution please suggest me

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9do3f.png)

Comment: run `git pull`, then `git push`.

Answer (score 0):

The error message indicates the issue is because the remote contains work that you do not have locally. So try to run `git pull` first to integrate the remote changes, then run `git push` again.