# How to grant permission for git push from bash?

Tags: bash, git, github, git-push

I am trying to create a new repository from git-bash.
I create a new rep from the GitHub interface
[image: Interface for new rep creation]

, and then run the following from bash

```sh
echo "# hello-world" >> README.md
git init
git add README.md
git commit -m "first commit"
git remote add origin https://github.com/leoUninova/hello-world.git
git push -u origin master
```

and got the error 'Permission denined':

```sh
 ~/tryal (master)
$ git push -u origin master
remote: Permission to leoUninova/hello-world.git denied to lqpwoeiruty.
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/leoUninova/hello-world.git/': The requested URL returned error: 403
```

I have seen answers to similar questions: [getting error after run git push -u origin master command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56016907/getting-error-after-run-git-push-u-origin-master-command), however it suggest a pull and I don't think that is the solution since I just copied the code from GitHub.

#### EDIT

My issue was with the Generic credentials, when I set them to this [image: Generic credentials for git] (with a password instead of blank), It worked fine.

Comment: I've done something similar with push. First i followed the steps [here](https://help.github.com/en/articles/generating-a-new-ssh-key-and-adding-it-to-the-ssh-agent) to be able to use ssh with github(safer than https version). Then I followed the rest of the instructions from [here](https://gist.github.com/developius/c81f021eb5c5916013dc) and it worked. Hope this helps.

Comment: I followed your steps, and got the ssh key. I successfully authenticated. Then git add-A gave erros: warning: could not open directory 'AppData/Local/Microsoft/Windows/INetCache/Content.IE5/': Permission denied . I changed the directory and git add-A worked. 
at this point git push gave me the exact same error as in my question

Comment: oh you're using Windows? Well I don't really know much more. Maybe you could check the [complete official guide](https://help.github.com/en/articles/connecting-to-github-with-ssh). Go to the "Testing your SSH connection" section to test if the connection works. Hope you find a solution. Good luck :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this command:

```
git remote set-url origin git@github.com:leoUninova/hello-world.git
```

and then try your `git push -u origin master`.

If this don't solve your problem try to delete your stored git credentials.

On Windows go to `Control Panel > User Accounts > Credential Manager > Windows Credentials > Generic Credentials` and remove the `Github` keys.

Comment: I did as you said. git push -u origin master gave the same error. So I have removed the Generic Credentials, what should I put as credentials ?

Comment: Your github username and password.

Comment: I ended up reinstalling GitHub and folllwing the instructions here: https://www.earthdatascience.org/workshops/intro-version-control-git/basic-git-commands/.  I'm accepting your answer because it modified my GitHub credentials, so I think you were right about the error being there